# combine multiple elements in a list with different indexes in r

Tags: r, list, loops

I have a list and I need to add together elements with different indexes. I'm struggling because I want to create a loop at different indexes.

```
data(aSAH)
rocobj <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
dat<-coords(rocobj, "all", ret=c("threshold","sensitivity", "specificity"), as.list=TRUE)
```

I want to create a function where I can look at all the `sensitivity/1-specificity` combos at all thresholds in a new data frame. I know threshold is found in `dat[1,]`, sensitivity is found in `dat[2,]` and specificity is found in `dat[3,]`. So I tried:

```
for (i in length(dat)) {
print(dat[1,i]
  print(dat[2,i]/(1-dat[3,i]))
}
```

Where I should end up with a dataframe that has `threshold` and `sensitivity/1-specificity`.

**DATA**

```html
dput(head(aSAH))
structure(list(gos6 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), outcome = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Good", "Poor"), class = "factor"), 
    gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Male", 
    "Female"), class = "factor"), age = c(42L, 37L, 42L, 27L, 
    42L, 48L), wfns = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), s100b = c(0.13, 
    0.14, 0.1, 0.04, 0.13, 0.1), ndka = c(3.01, 8.54, 8.09, 10.42, 
    17.4, 12.75)), .Names = c("gos6", "outcome", "gender", "age", 
"wfns", "s100b", "ndka"), row.names = 29:34, class = "data.frame")
```

**EDIT**
One answer:

```
dat_transform <- as.data.frame(t(dat))
dat_transform <- dat_transform %>% mutate(new=sensitivity/(1-specificity))
```

Comment: Why have you got `i` repeated in both loops?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I saw an example similar to my question do that. I updated the  function; I think this is more correct?

Comment: Just omit the `as.list=TRUE` (since you want a data frame, not a list) and use Ronak's solution.

Comment: Yes, I tried Ronak's solution without the `as.list` argument and I'm still getting the errors I wrote below in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
transform(t, res = sensitivity/(1-specificity))[c(1, 4)]
```

Or with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

t %>%
  mutate(res = sensitivity/(1-specificity)) %>%
  select(threshold, res)
```

Also note that `t` is a default function in R to tranpose dataframe so better to use some other variable name for the dataframe.

Comment: thanks for that nice tip re: t. Unfortunately I am getting an error message for both solutions: `Error in sensitivity/1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator` and `Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"`. I think the first refers to sensitivity and specificity being characters, but it says I cannot change them using `as.numeric` since they are vectors. `t` is a double so I changed it to a list using `t<-lapply(t, as.numeric)` but that does not make option 2 work either

Comment: That's strange, this works for me as it is for the data shared. For the error `Error in sensitivity/1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator` it means your data is of other class than numeric and the second error suggests that `t` is a matrix. You can convert it into dataframe and try again.

Comment: I'm still having trouble.  I `rm()` all my functions and data and tried both solutions again but I'm still getting errors. I converted the matrix to a dataframe and get the error `Error: Columns `all`, `all`, `all`,...` .  I added the additional argument in the `coords` function (updated the question); `str()` shows that it is all numeric yet solution 1 doesn't work either. Any thoughts?

Comment: @PleaseHelp Can you share the data that you are using with `dput` ? `dput(head(aSAH))` ? Let me see if I can reproduce the same error at my end.

Comment: I played around with your solution and got another one, which I added to my post. But can you help me understand why your two original solutions didn't work just so I can learn? They seem like elegant solutions!

Comment: @PleaseHelp There is no `sensitivity` or `specificity` column in your data but this works on your data `transform(asah, res = s100b/(1-ndka))`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I was more interested in trying to understand your first two solutions and why they weren't working. I don't know why it wasn't working but your solution helped to teach me about `transform` which helped me figure out the solution, so thanks!

Comment: @PleaseHelp I don't know why you say they aren't working. They are working for me for the data you shared.

Comment: I'm not sure either; I copied and pasted my code directly from my R script and ran it multiple times in an empty environment. I don't know if data gets updated through different R versions. I'm using an older version of R. But using your suggestions to convert my data into a dataframe and then `transform` gave me my answer! :)